# Перестает работать блютус мышь вместе с клавиатурой. Мак Бук Аир

Tags: mac, bluetooth, мышь

Пользовался блютус мышью (не родной) с МакБук Аир.
На днях собрал кастомную механическую клавиатуру.

Проблема в следующем: когда подключаю клавиатуру (тоже по блютус), мышь перестает реагировать на движения, но кнопки на мыши, при этом, работают исправно, а вот курсор либо вообще не перемещается, либо хаотичные дерганья.
Оба девайса при этом подключены, т.е. никаких отключений или "отваливания".

Как только отключаю клавиатуру - все отлично, как и раньше - мышь начинает работать как и положено.
Не пойму в чем проблема и как ее решить.
Наверняка кто то сталкивался?